# Using Webby and Capistrano to Deploy

Tags: ruby, capistrano, webby

I have a very simple site using webby and capistrano.  It is based off another site I help with, but in general I'm historically not a Linux or Ruby dude.

Current Cap deploy pulls from my git hub repo (https://github.com/cromwellryan/cincycleancoders.com), moves it to current, and then calls webby to build things.  It does this in $HOME//webapps//current on my hosting provider.

My hosting is shared and doesn't have webby gem installed on the system, so I've attempted using their recommended steps to install the gems locally (2nd answer [here](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/1741/how-to-install-rubygems-locally)).  I've installed them to ~/webapps/current/ but unfortunately webby isn't in the path and I don't think it should be for local gems (?).

In the end I'm trying to figure out how to execute the webby command, preferrably with a relative path.

Let me know what more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked webby has some built in deployment scripts that allow you to deploy via ssh.

Is there are reason you are pulling from github instead of deploying directly from your computer?  It would simplify things a little more.

Comment: Best Practice.  I don't always work on the same machine and other people do work on it as well.  We push to the github repo and then cap deploy.